# My app is successfully build but it keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a school project to make an android app. But when I run the app, it keeps showing things like this in the logcat. I am a newbie in android studio. Please help me.

```
2020-04-03 00:10:26.352 31907-31907/com.example.citypage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.citypage, PID: 31907
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citypage/com.example.citypage.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.citypage:layout/activity_main: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.citypage:layout/activity_main: ScrollView can host only one direct child
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:599)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.citypage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
2020-04-03 00:10:26.377 31907-31907/com.example.citypage I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31907 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Read what the error is telling you `IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Comment: yass! thankyou for answering. it's working already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ScrollView in your `:layout/activity_main` file, you might have multiple child within ScrollView, remove them or combine them.

In ScrollView you can not place more then one direct child.

Comment: what is the best way to combine them? should i merge them into relative layout?

Comment: Yes you should combine them in LinearLayout

Comment: @darkcavalierr depends on your UI and how many views are there, whatever layout you can use, but use them in one.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says '`ScrollView can host only one direct child`'. Make sure you only have one view inside your ScrollView by wrapping all the other views inside a LinearLayout or another Layout view.

Answer (score 0):

Keep only one Layout inside `ScrollView`. As it can only host one direct child. Something like below code. Its not compulsion to have `ConstraintLayout`, any layout works. But just one direct child in `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ----- //child Layout 1

        ----- //child layout 2

     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sure, Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Your error is about Scroll view you must us`enter code here`e only 1 direct child in Scroll view yhen put all needed view inside that child view.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <Linearlayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ----- //child Layout 1

        ----- //child layout 2

     </Linearlayout>

 </ScrollView>
```